# Restrict an app for particular IMEI number

Tags: android, imei

I have developing an app of our corporate Telephone Directory.  To restrict its distribution to non-corporate persons, I have to restrict the app to particular IMEI number. 
      So whoever wants my app, he will register with email id and IMEI number and using that IMEI number I should deliver the .apk to him.

```
  So please help me how and where can I store the IMEI number in .apk file.
```

(I am using Adobe Flash builder and I am trying on Flex platform).

Comment: If imeis list is static you can store within a resource file and read it from app. Otherwise, if the imeis list can chage, you need to store it in server-side (to add, modify or delete) and retrieve from mobile application.

Comment: First, Thank you sir for reply.  What I do is For each user I ask his IMEI number and when he send via email, I will put it in package and compile and send him the app. Its a single IMEI app. No list. Please help me in which file I can Store the IMEI and then call that file during app execution.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to your explanation in comment. I would say to you that I think that is not a good "identificaiton" solution. I encourage to you to have a single app and check IMEIs with a database in server side.

Also I have to say that an advanced user could FAKE the IMEI of the device.

But anyway, if you want to make your solution, the code is quite simple. You just need to store the IMEI with a static variable and check it in the main activity. 
If the IMEI is correct run the app, otherwise show a message and close. That's the way you will have a "single IMEI app"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String AUTHORIZED_IMEI = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get device IMEI
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceImei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        if (AUTHORIZED_IMEI.equals(deviceImei)) {
            // AUTHORIZED
            // Code to run within onCreate
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "DEVICE NOT AUTHORIZED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to write permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

> NOTE: In Android 6, you need to handle this permisison in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static String authorisedImei = "xxxxxxxx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        // ActivityCompat#requestPermissions;
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        } else {

            return;
        }
    }
        String deviceImei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        if (authorisedImei.equals(deviceImei)) {
            textView = findViewById(R.id.text2);
            textView.setText(deviceImei + " - Authorised");
        }

        else {
          textView = findViewById(R.id.text2);
          textView.setText(deviceImei + " - Not authorised");

            new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textView = findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    finish();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation for your solution